# Is it possible to iterate over nested arrays with arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrow-functions

A bit of a JS n00b, just starting out and such, and I currently have a nested array that I want to easily change values in.

```
var rects = [[new Rect, new Rect, new Rect, new Rect, new Rect],
             [new Rect, new Rect, new Rect, new Rect, new Rect]]
```

Now I know I could always do

```
for(let i = 0; i < rects.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < rects[i].length; j++{
        rects[i][j].pos.x = 30;
        rects[i][j].pos.y = 30;
    }
}
```

but I was wondering if I could use (for lack of a better phrasing) nested arrow functions to do something like

```
rects.forEach(rect => {
    rect.forEach(thing => {
        thing.pos.x = 30;
        thing.pos.y = 30;
    });
});
```

and have the same effect as the for loop above? They just look so much cleaner and my code looks like a rats nest of English.

Comment: The best way to answer this kind of question is to try it and see if it works. There's no reason to ask a bunch of strangers on the internet :).

Comment: I would use map instead of forEach because it returns a new Array, but it is just a personal preference

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In short: yes you can. If you've tried it and are getting errors, that would be a separate and more useful question to ask.

Comment: Am I using the correct syntax in that example? Because currently if I try and do that exact "nested arrow function" in my code, nothing happens.

Comment: How do you know nothing happens? What are the values of `rects` before and after your function runs? Add some `console.log` statements to test all this.

Answer (score -1):

A technique that works in any version of JS is to use the for loop to get a reference to the object you want to work with.  You have to be careful using it with arrays that contain falsey values which is not so in your example.

```
for (var i = 0, r; r = rects[i]; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, thing; thing = r[j]; j++) {
        thing.pos.x = 30;
        thing.pos.y = 30;
    }
}
```